# Passivating Form Action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to passivate form action because i submit the form with js. But if there is form action js doesn't work and page redirects action url. I remove form tags and put div tags with #combination id but it didn't work neither
js:

```
  $("#combination").submit(function(){
  var url = "www.myurl.com/?view=listen&";

  var i = 0;
  $("input:checked").each(function(){
      url += "tag[" + i + "]" + $(this).val() + "&";
      i++;
  });
  alert(url);
  location.href = url;

});
```

html:

```
    <form id="combination" action="" method="get" name="combination" target="_self">
    <?php foreach($top_tags as $top_tag):?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="<?php echo $top_tag['tag_name'];?>" /><?php echo $top_tag['tag_name'];?><br />
        <?php endforeach;?> 
    <input name="" type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Resetting the location like that is not going to submit the form ...

Comment: You can't submit a form using JavaScript without Ajax.  Is that what you intend to do?  What is passivate?  Also, you do not prevent the default form submission event from occurring, which is why the page refreshes.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, that's not only ajax, you can form.submit()

Comment: @dmi3y that's already called when you click the submit button

Comment: It would be much easier if you open another question where you're describing what you want to do, because the method you're using is obviously not working.

Comment: @deceze: Passivate, Passivating are all related to [Passivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passivation_%28chemistry%29), which in chemistry and Engineering  refers to a material becoming "passive". Though the word itself makes sense I don't think it is being used correctly in this question.

Comment: @François OK. :) "... is not a word *in this context*" then.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, yea but in general .submit() != ajax, it is just programatically submit:)

Comment: @dmi3y but she doesn't want to do that since it will refresh the page!

Comment: redirection will refresh page anyway, it is like many work for something could be solved on server side with one if statement and header location setting in PHP

Answer (score 2):

you have to prevent the default behavior of the form with "preventDefault" and than start your ajax-call or what ever ;).

```
$("#combination").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = "www.myurl.com/?view=listen&";

  var i = 0;
  $("input:checked").each(function(){
      url += "tag[" + i + "]" + $(this).val() + "&";
      i++;
  });
  alert(url);
  location.href = url;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you really could not call the handler this way:

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

> handler(eventObject)A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

basically what happend, instead of submitting form you did redirection.

Think about chain:

1. you call submit method for form, using jquery.
2. while the event triggered for form, but before the form actually submitted you change the location.
3. this cancels submitting and instead redirect you to whatever

If you really want things doing this way you may do it into the two ways:

1. redirection on the server side after the form is submitted
2. as it was said use `ajax` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ submitting into the handler and make disable default action either way

   ```
   $("#combination").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       // code here
   });
   ```

   OR

   ```
    $("#combination").submit(function(event){
       // code here
       return false;
    });
   ```